# HTML / JavaScript - Post message on facebook wall from my web

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, sdk

this question may sound stupid, but im getting frustrated from searching around, and i cant manage to do that:

I want to create a button on my web (not an applications if that matters), and when the user will click on it, it will post a dynamic message on his wall.

Do i have to use javascript SDK for it, or is there a simpler way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use Facebook Connect (Facebook SDK for Javascript).

Take a look at this:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.2

But before use this API you need to create an APP ID in the Facebook developers page and use this ID to authenticate through OAuth:

https://developers.facebook.com/apps

This link also explains you how to use Facebook SDK with jQuery

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/howto/jquery

I hope it helps.

Edited:

If you want something really simple. You can use Social Plugins to allow the user share your website. But I'm not really sure if you want to post a custom message for the user.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/

Comment: Helped alot! i couldnt find before all the requirements such as creating APP ID. Thanks